# Junit : Verify a static void method is called inside a final Class

Tags: java, junit, powermockito

There is a static void custom log  method inside a legacy final class which takes in two parameters  and calls a method in another class to log the actual data in a logger (Console or file depeding on the confurations). Now I just would like to know if there is way  to verify if `log(Object param1, String param2)` is called at least once  ?

Please note: the `SomeClass.actualLogMethod()` is outside the scope of my test so i just need to verify `delete()` method only

I saw some solutions here on how to mock a static method that has a return type other than void. But how can I mock a static method that returns void which is inside of a final class, as in the case below? Is there a way i can atelast verify using Powermock its called. Like using `Mockito.verify()` or something similar?

```
public final class LegacyFinalClass{

      public static void log(String param1, Object param2) {
                SomeClass.actualLogMethod(dt, ss);
      }

 }

@Test
public void testDelete() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(LegacyFinalClass.class);  
    Object param1 = "logObject"
    String param2 = "some string"
    Mockito.verify(LegacyFinalClass.class).getMethod("log",new Class[]{Object.class, String.class).invoke(param1, parm2);

}

But this fails with this error : 
Wanted but not invoked LegacyFinalClass.getMethod(
    "logDuration",
    interface org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger,
    interface org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger,
    long
);
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.doMethodCall(MockGateway.java:182)
    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.doMethodCall(MockGateway.java:164)
    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.methodCall(MockGateway.java:134)
    at LegacyFinalClass.log(LegacyTest.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:326)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:761)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:207)
```

I was thinking if i need to call on `PowerMockito.doNothing().doCallRealMethod().` but i m not sure how am i suppse to use it in my case when u just need to verify if the log method is called .

Comment: Andy that class /package outside the scope of my test that is why I need to verify this one is called.

Comment: Imo, this loggin step should be tested while testing the SomeClass class. There is no logic to test here. I don't think you should test something that can not happen.

Comment: actualLogMethod is a static method ?

Comment: Yes actualLogMethod is also a static void method. But I m not suppose to test that class/package. I kjust need to just verify  `delete()` is called

Comment: where do you call delete in the test?

Comment: why do you mock MyFinalClass? how does it correlate with the case?

Comment: please try to add enough code for us to have a clear picture. A lot is missing now

Comment: Maciej , I had a type-O in there , I meant log not delete. This is all the code there is . There is a legacy final class which contains a static void log method which i need to verify from my test that it has been called.

Comment: ok got it but where do you call the method under test? I mean there has to be a method you trying to test and the LegacyFinalClass.log is called from there right?

Comment: It makes sense to test whether Someclass.actualLog is called when calling LegacyFinalClass.log.. but that it.. maybe thats what you meant?

Comment: Yes it would be great if thats possible from my test code but here i am just am suppose  to verify if the LegacyFinalClass.log is called